# why grep promt "Invalid range end"?

Tags: grep

I have a file `a`:

```
$ cat a 
abcd
kaka
```

when using the command:

```
$ grep -e '[a-d]' a
abcd
kaka
```

It works well, but why those command is not right?

```
$ grep -e '[\x61-\x74]' a 
grep: Invalid range end

$ grep -e '[\u0061-\u0074]' a 
grep: Invalid range end
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that your version of `grep` supports `PCRE` ("Perl-compatible regular expressions"), you can try:

```
grep -P '[\x61-\x74]' a
```

This would return the expected output:

```
abcd
kaka
```

Comment: @edwardtorvalds hex 61 which is lowercase a

Comment: Won't work for unicode though: 

`grep -P '[\u0061-\u0074]' a` yields"
grep: PCRE does not support \L, \l, \N{name}, \U, or \u