# Using a unicode capture group in a regex with grep

Tags: regex, grep

I am trying to capture all words (or letters) of a given unicode alphabet, in a regular expression with `grep`. Seems to be some trouble with the combination of grep and that sort of a regex.

I'll spare of you my failed attempts at it, sufficing in saying that the following works fine in https://regexr.com:

```
[\u0590-\u05FF]
```

But not in any form I tried with `grep` on Ubuntu linux.

Comment: Here's [one thing that didn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15607036/why-grep-promt-invalid-range-end/16298835#comment82260358_16298835) nonetheless

Comment: What is sample text you're trying to match?

Comment: You need to use `grep -oP '[\x{0590}-\x{05FF}]'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew hey thanks, this actually works! curly braces I guess then! you might post this as an accepted answer if you like

Comment: Why you consider it duplicate is beyond me. Just read the way the referenced question is asked and suggest any similarity.... ;)